# Pymongo | Extract document in reverse order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to extract the documents from a collection in reverse order.

Implemented it like this :

```
documents = list(collection.find({'timestamp': {'$gte': start_ts, '$lt': end_ts}},{'_id': 0}).sort('timestamp',-1))
```

But in this case it is yielding the result as it is not in reverse order.

Please let me know how it can be done in one line, don't want to use sort on list?

Comment: Provide a few examples of data with the timestamp.

Comment: [{'timestamp': 1609834941.8455691, 'shift_count_avg': 4, 'status': 'good pay', 'status1': 'testing'}, {timestamp': 1609834938.093422, 'shift_count_avg': 3, 'status': 'good pay', 'status1': 'testing'}, {'timestamp': 1609834933.296117, 'shift_count_avg': 2, 'status': 'good pay', 'status1': 'testing'}, {'timestamp': 1609834920.8015761, 'shift_count_avg': 1, 'status': 'good pay', 'status1': 'testing'}]